# Compiler calls copy operator instead of move operator

Tags: c++, move

I *did* find an exact question here beforehand, but I don't have the same cause of issue (or at least I think so). My `AnimatedSprite` class has a `Timer` member, which is made to be non-copyable (explicitly deleted both copy ctor and operator= ). Yet when I try to initalize a sprite in some other class's ctor, I get an error saying I'm referencing the deleted copy operator=.

Timer.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <set>

class Timer
{
public:
    Timer() :
        currentTime_{0},
        expirationTime_{0}
    {}
    Timer(unsigned expirationTime) :
        currentTime_{ expirationTime },
        expirationTime_{ expirationTime }
    {
        timers_.insert(this);
    }

    ~Timer() {
        timers_.erase(this);
    }
    // Here
    Timer(const Timer& other) = delete;
    Timer& operator=(const Timer& other) = delete;

    Timer(Timer&& other) = default;
    Timer& operator=(Timer&& other) = default;


    //   Assumes the user knows if |this| is active or not
    unsigned currentTime() const { return currentTime_; }

    bool active() const { return currentTime_ < expirationTime_; }
    bool expired() const { return !active(); }
    void reset() { currentTime_ = 0; }
    void disable() { currentTime_ = expirationTime_; }


    static void updateAll(unsigned elapsedTime);

private:

    void update(unsigned elapsedTime) {
        if (active()) {
            currentTime_ += elapsedTime;
        }
    }


    static std::set<Timer*> timers_;
    unsigned currentTime_;
    const unsigned expirationTime_;

};
```

AnimatedSprite.h

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include "Globals.h"
#include "Sprite.h"
#include "Timer.h"


class Sprite;
class Graphics;

class AnimatedSprite : public Sprite
{
public:
    AnimatedSprite() = default;
    AnimatedSprite(Graphics& graphics, const std::string& filePath,
        int sourceX, int sourceY, int width, int height,
        unsigned frameLength, unsigned frameCount);

    void update(bool once = false);
    const bool completedOnce() const { return once_; }

private:

    Timer frameTimer_;
    unsigned currentFrame_{ 0 };
    unsigned totalFrames_;
    bool once_{ false };    //  if true, plays animation once
};
```

And then I do this:

```
sprite_ = AnimatedSprite( graphics, "Resource/NpcSym.png", 0, 1, 16, 16, 50, 5 );
```

Shouldn't the move operator be called here ? Isn't my RHS in the line above an rvalue?

Comment: You will want Timer's move constructor to also insert the new instance into the timer set. Edit : Since default constructed instances don't seem to be getting registered, you may also want the move constructor to unregister the moved-from instance, and have the move assignment operator do the same.

Comment: Can you show the definition of `Sprite`? What is the type of `sprite_`?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux 
That actually did the trick: I defined my own move operator and everything went ok. Could you elaborate on that a bit more ? What did you mean by default constructed instances ? Could it be related to the fact I'm also getting warnings for uninitialized values in some other classes even though I defaulted the empty constructor ?

Comment: @ezegoing
_sprite is of type AnimatedSprite. I just named it that way in my other class.

Comment: @monolith937 Well, I noticed that when the default constructor (I think you called it "the empty constructor") is used the instance is not added to `timers_`. From that I deduce that only "active" or "running" instances should be in that set and it seems probable that any moved-from instance would not qualify and should be removed from the set.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux
Hm, okay from our point of view that makes perfect sense, but how would my VisualStudio compiler have any clue about that ? I mean, the thought couldn't cross my mind.

Comment: @monolith937 The reason doing this fixed it is because you have `const unsigned expirationTime_;`. Having a `const` member means that the default move constructor and assignment operator don't work. By default moving an object means moving all it's members by a `const` member can't be moved from or assigned a new value to. You should probably avoid `const` members in general. Look at what the version you implemented does with that member. It probably doesn't try to move it. But you probably want it to because it's part of the state.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux 
Alright, one more thing I wanted to check. When I manually define my move operator with insertion in the set of my newly created object, should I explicitly `erase` the `other` from the set or does its destructor do the job ?

Comment: @monolith937 Moving from an instance doesn't destroy it right away, it just becomes "moved from". Some times the moved from instance can stick around for a while, so it's probavly best to `erase` it right away. It's convenient when moved from instance behave like default constructed instances and you don't seen to register those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something about your `AnimatedSprite` prevents it from being movable.  Once that is eliminated, it tries to copy.  And you get your error.

Possible something in `Sprite` blocks it from being moved.  Or something in `Timer`; `=default` can become `=delete` if you cannot move the thing.

One technique I use is to inject static asserts about such assumptions.

```
static_assert( std::is_move_assignable<Sprite>{}, "Cannot move Sprite" );
static_assert( std::is_move_constructible<Sprite>{}, "Cannot move Sprite" );
static_assert( std::is_move_assignable<Timer>{}, "Cannot move Timer" );
static_assert( std::is_move_constructible<Timer>{}, "Cannot move Timer" );
```

Now, using my compiler-in-brain, I can see:

```
const unsigned expirationTime_;
```

will block move assignment on `Timer`.

Backing up to design:

```
sprite_ = AnimatedSprite( graphics, "Resource/NpcSym.png", 0, 1, 16, 16, 50, 5 );
```

does it make sense to *assign* one currently animating sprite over another?

I doubt it.

I'd `=delete` `operator=(&&)`.

Replace `sprite_` with an `std::optional<AnimatedSprite>`, and do:

```
sprite_.emplace( graphics, "Resource/NpcSym.png", 0, 1, 16, 16, 50, 5 );
```

which is often far more sane than having a "sprite that is in a state that isn't a sprite".

Comment: It's rare that move semantics doesn't make sense. Conceptually moving an animated sprite certainly makes sense. The `const` member is probably the result of being overzealous with `const` correctness.

Comment: Yes, I did realize my design was flawed, I was just curious as to why it wouldn't work. Had no clue you couldn't move const members. Will read more about std::optional. Your solution seems like a nice save.

Comment: @monolith937 You cannot assign to const members, for obvious reasons (they are `const` cannot be changed).  Move **assigning** involves assigning-to.

Comment: @monolith937 I'll reiterate that `expirationTime` is part of the state of a timer and should not be `const`. Losing that constraint is worth supporting move semantincs in almost all cases. You can instead enforce the invariance of given timer *value*'s `expirationTime` through the interface, for example by not providing a `set` member.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux 
Just to clarify, what did you mean by 'enforcing the invariance' ? Is there some other approach I could use to make `expirationTime` invariant without the `const` keyword ?

Comment: @mono yes, don't change it.  And you enforce it by making it private and only written at construction/assignment, and only read via access method.